# MongoDB OR not in a top level

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to build a query like this:

```
"i_field": {
    "$or": [{
            query_1
        }, {
            query_2
        }
    ]
}
```

However mongo throws exception `"Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $or"` since I must use `$or` in top level (or that's my understanding so far).

Working OR in top level query: **(but that's not what I need)**

```
"$or": [{
        "i_field": query_1
    }, {
        "i_field": query_2
    }
]
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how could I make this query work?

**Edit** (real exmple):

```
"i_field": {
    "$or": [{
            "$gte": 3.5,
            "$lt": 88.5
        }, {
            "$eq": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting `$or` in the top level is the way to go:

```
"$or":[
   { "i_field":{"$gte": 3.5, "$lt": 88.5}}, 
   { "i_field": null}
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qKxllF9GLWr)

Answer (score 0):

Use $in instead:

```
{ "i_field": { "$in": [query_1, query_2] } }
```

Comment: In works only for values, not queries. Getting same error `Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $in`